# Alternate port for c2s on jabberd2

Tags: xmpp

I'm trying to add a second port for c2s connections to my existing jabberd2.  Unfortunately, it wasn't as simple as adding another `<port>` element to c2s.xml.  Can one instance of c2s listen on multiple ports or will I need to add a whole second c2s instance?

If I do need another instance of c2s, resources for setting that up would be very appreciated.  Documentation for that scenario seems pretty sparse and mostly restricted to multiple-domain setups, whereas I want connections to either port to be identical in every other respect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use port forwarding to forward connections to one port to another port.

i.e. on Linux:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 1234 -j REDIRECT --to-port 5222
```

Comment: This is similar to the workaround I have in place for now.  My router is forwarding both ports to the one port on the jabber server.  I'm still hoping for a way to do it in jabberd2, but I'm not sure the hassle of multiple c2s instances is worth it.